# Как правильно организовать навигацию через ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть страница с несколькими "вкладками", что-то вроде горизонтального аккордиона.
В каждой вкладке достаточно большое кол-во контента, включая графику, поэтому скорость загрузки всей страница оставляет желать лучшего.

Можно сделать подгрузку содержимого вкладок через `.load()` либо `$.get`, но в таком случае подгружаемый контент не будет индексироваться поисковиками.

Вижу решением задачи следующие:

1. Делаем отдельные страницы под каждую вкладку со всеми элементами
   управления.
2. В каждую из этих страниц помещаем контент, соответствующей этой
   вкладке.
3. При переходе по вкладкам подгружаем соответствующие страницы с
   выборкой по селектору (блоку с контентом).

Отсюда у меня вопросы:

- Как сделать эту самую выборку по селектору при подгрузке через
  `$.get`?
- Правильное ли вообще такое решение? Или есть другое, более
  практичное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе решение приемлемо. 
Для обновления состояния браузерной строки можно использовать histroy в js, например:

```js
$('.ajax_load').click(function(e) => {

  e.preventDefault(); // отменяем переход
  
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  
  $('#content').load(link + '?ajax_load=true'); // загружаем страницу
  
  history.pushState({}, title, link); // меняем адресную строку без перезагрузки
})
```

```html
<a href="/link1/" title="Link title1">link1</a>
<a href="/link2/" title="Link title2">link2</a>

<div id="content"></div>
```

P.S. Только не забудьте убрать header и футер из загружаемых страниц с помощью ajax